# Getting the error NoMethodError in Users#index when using Rails 5.0.6, Oracle 12c Ruby 2.5 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, ubuntu-16.04

I have a very small test `App` using only one table, Users having couple columns. The purpose is to find a way to migrate a `Ruby on Rails` App from using `PostgreSQL` to using `Oracle`.

The exactly same `App` works perfect if I am using `PostgreSQL`.
When switching to `Oracle`, I am getting this error (for the code in the file `application.html.erb`):

> NoMethodError in Users#index Showing
>   /home/levi/ror/testora/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where
>   line #7 raised: undefined method `success?' for nil:NilClass Extracted
>   source (around line #7):
>
> ```
>     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
>
>     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
>     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
>   </head>
> ```

The error occurs when the URL for Users Index is used
http://localhost:3000/users

Instead of the error, I am expecting to see something like this:

```
Users
Name    Dob         Gender  
Levi    1963-07-31  M      Show Edit Destroy
Adina   1966-09-02  F      Show Edit Destroy
New User
```

If I am commenting these 2 lines

> ```
> <%#= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
> <%#= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
> ```

I am getting a basic page rendered as mention above.

Here is my `application.html.erb` file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testora</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

The Gemfile contains these lines:

```
# Use oracle as the database for Active Record
gem 'ruby-oci8', '~>2.2'
# Use oracle as the database for Active Record
gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', '1.7.0'
```

And I am able to test / work with the Users controller and model when using `rails db` and `rails console`.

I am suspecting that this is related to assets pipeline and turbo-links.
I don't know what the error may be and how to fix it?

Comment: can you post a full error backtrace?